# SuperDev mode runs fine ,but compiled version tells 404....undefined.cache.js

Tags: gwt

I have ubuntu 16.04 64 bit(with german UI language) + chrome 54.0.2840.71 (English is default language), and doubt this is a language problem,and my *.gwt.xml has these lines:

```
     <!-- I18N related stuffs -->
     <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N" />
     <extend-property name="locale" values="en" />
     <extend-property name="locale" values="zh_CN" />
     <set-property name="locale" value="en,zh_CN" />
     <set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en" />
     <set-property name="user.agent" value="safari" />
```

Only Chinese and English constants are provided,so what is the problem?

Comment: Can you provide more information please? When and where does the 404 occur? What's the complete error message,...

Answer (score 0):

After changing to this,it works fine:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N" />
<extend-property name="locale" values="de" />
<extend-property name="locale" values="en" />
<extend-property name="locale" values="zh_CN" />
<set-property name="locale" value="en,zh_CN,de" />
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en" />
```